# How can we convert a range of table types (latex,org) to html when org-exporting to html?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

Suppose that I have 3 types of tables in an org file, A latex table, an org-table, and a html-table. How can we to export these table as html tables when org-exporting to html?

```
# #+BEGIN_LaTeX
# \begin{table}
# \begin{center}
# \begin{tabular}{l c }
# \hline
#       & Model 1 \\
# \hline
# (Intercept) & $0.06$       \\
#       & $(0.10)$     \\
# x           & $1.02^{***}$ \\
#       & $(0.10)$     \\
# \hline
# R$^2$       & 0.53         \\
# Adj. R$^2$  & 0.53         \\
# Num. obs.   & 100          \\
# RMSE        & 1.05         \\
# \hline
# \multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
# \end{tabular}
# \caption{Statistical models}
# \label{table:coefficients}
# \end{center}
# \end{table}
# #+END_LaTeX



|-----------+-----|
| groceries | qty |
|-----------+-----|
| apple     |   1 |
| banana    |   5 |
|-----------+-----|




#+BEGIN_HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<table cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border: none;">
<caption align="bottom" style="margin-top:0.3em;">Statistical models</caption>
<tr>
<th style="text-align: left; border-top: 2px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding-right: 12px;"></th>
<th style="text-align: left; border-top: 2px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding-right: 12px;"><b>Model 1</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">(Intercept)</td>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">-0.10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;"></td>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">(0.11)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">x</td>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">1.33<sup style="vertical-align: 0px;">***</sup></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;"></td>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">(0.11)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-top: 1px solid black;">R<sup style="vertical-align: 0px;">2</sup></td>
<td style="border-top: 1px solid black;">0.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">Adj. R<sup style="vertical-align: 0px;">2</sup></td>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">0.59</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">Num. obs.</td>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;">100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">RMSE</td>
<td style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">1.07</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 12px; border: none;" colspan="2"><span style="font-size:0.8em"><sup style="vertical-align: 0px;">***</sup>p &lt; 0.001, <sup style="vertical-align: 0px;">**</sup>p &lt; 0.01, <sup style="vertical-align: 0px;">*</sup>p &lt; 0.05</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
#+END_HTML
```

Comment: How do you want LaTeX table to be exported? In case exporting it as an image is OK, then you might be interested in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467870/org-mode-html-export also, look at the `by-backend` macro which allows you to export the same block (of code) differently, depending on the backend (LaTeX blocks can be also inserted as blocks of code): http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html#sec-4-3

Comment: @wvxvw sorry for the late reply. That was exactly what i needed. You saved me a lot of work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to wvxvw for pointing to the answer.  I don't deserve any credit, just gathering the information here.

The key thing here is to use the header that will export in latex directly when exporting to latex (C-e-C-l-l).

But it will generate an image first when exporting to html.(C-e-C-h-h)

you need to put the following in your .emacs as well:

```
(setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")
(defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
`(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
```

You can have more info about this [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html#sec-4-3)

So here is the way to do it.

```
#+header: :results (by-backend (html "results.png") (t "raw"))
#+header: :results (by-backend (pdf "latex") (t "raw"))
#+BEGIN_SRC latex
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c }
\hline
  & Model 1 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $0.06$       \\
  & $(0.10)$     \\
x           & $1.02^{***}$ \\
  & $(0.10)$     \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.53         \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.53         \\
Num. obs.   & 100          \\
RMSE        & 1.05         \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
#+END_SRC


|-----------+-----|
| groceries | qty |
|-----------+-----|
| apple     |   1 |
| banana    |   5 |
|-----------+-----|
```