# org mode - export latex inline image to html

Tags: org-mode

I can see inline image in emacs but when export to html,the image is not displayed. Even if in pdf export, it display a text ([[file:latex.jpg]]) but not the output image.

":exports both" is there but only code exported!

```
#+HEADER: :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz} \\usetikzlibrary{chains}")
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :fit yes :imagemagick yes :iminoptions -density 300 :exports both :file latex.jpg
\newcommand\ann[3][]{
    \draw[arr,#1,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] ([yshift=-0.5cm]#2.south) node[below] {#3} -- (#2.south);
}
\definecolor{col1}{RGB} {238,51,34}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB} {153,221,153}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB} {255,255,51}
\tiny\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=C1 going right,>=latex,node distance=0pt,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex,
box/.style={draw,fill=yellow!5,rectangle, minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=.5cm,outer sep=0},
arr/.style={->,line width=0.2pt}
]
\foreach \val/\col [count=\i] in {1/col1,2/col1,3/col1,6/col2,5/col2,2/col2,4/col3} {
  \node[box,fill=\col,on chain] (N\i) {\val};
}
\ann[black]{N3}{cur};
\ann[black]{N5}{index};
\ann[black]{N7}{key};
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: How this [post](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-LaTeX.html#sec-4-3) help as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the output has a extra tag BEGIN_LaTex/END_LaTex there, it will impact on HTML render.

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
[[file:latex.jpg]]
#+END_LaTeX
```

Add `:results raw file` will remove the extra tag then the inline image will show on HTML output.

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:latex.jpg]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the image in the jpeg file?

This configuration works for me. But I don't know how it works exactly.
The best info I can give you is from this post [How can we convert a range of table types (latex,org) to html when org-exporting to html?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17765/how-can-we-convert-a-range-of-table-types-latex-org-to-html-when-org-exporting).

I'm using this macro which I found in the link above. I recommend putting it in your init file. From my understanding you can handle how latex export blocks depending whether you export to latex or html.

```
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs :export no
   (setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")
   (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
   `(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
   #+END_SRC



#+LATEX_HEADER:\usetikzlibrary{chains}
#+LATEX_HEADER:\usepackage{tikz}
#+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick



#+header: :results (by-backend (pdf "latex") (t "raw"))
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :results output graphics :file test.png
\newcommand\ann[3][]{
    \draw[arr,#1,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] ([yshift=-0.5cm]#2.south) node[below] {#3} -- (#2.south);
}
\definecolor{col1}{RGB} {238,51,34}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB} {153,221,153}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB} {255,255,51}
\tiny\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=C1 going right,>=latex,node distance=0pt,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex,
box/.style={draw,fill=yellow!5,rectangle, minimum width=.5cm,minimum height=.5cm,outer sep=0},
arr/.style={->,line width=0.2pt}
]
\foreach \val/\col [count=\i] in {1/col1,2/col1,3/col1,6/col2,5/col2,2/col2,4/col3} {
  \node[box,fill=\col,on chain] (N\i) {\val};
}
\ann[black]{N3}{cur};
\ann[black]{N5}{index};
\ann[black]{N7}{key};
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_SRC
```